# (UIMA) Create PEAR file from AnalysisEngine objects

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I have two AnalysisEngine objects that I initialize manually. One is RUTA based, while the other is simply installed from a pear file. What I need to to is create an aggregate AnalysisEngine that runs these two annotators and package that new engine as a Pear file.

I have seen the [PackageCreator](https://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.3.0-incubating/docs/api/org/apache/uima/pear/tools/PackageCreator.html) class, however I was unable to find any examples on how to use it correctly.